# Trying to make a percentage calculator but there is an error

Tags: c#, calculation

simply code is this when i press the button it should take valus from textbox and process it but first line is giving an error can anyone help me to fix it

```
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(A);// this line giving an error
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(B);
        int k = (x * 100) / y;
        string z = k.ToString();
        finalstring.Text= z;
```

Comment: What is the type and value of `A`? Is the `A` a valid number?

Comment: What is A? what input you are giving?

Comment: a textbox is 10 and b textbox is 1

Comment: What does “an error” mean? What error do you get exactly? Have you tried debugging your code and looked at your variables’ values and types? Is “A” the text box itself or the text of the text box?

Comment: Have you tried ```int.Parse(A);```?

Comment: System.InvalidCastException its giving this error i dont know what is this mean it my first time seeing it

Comment: i tried int.Parse(A) it gives same error

Comment: Can you then share what ```A```'s value is?

Comment: What is `A`. Is it the textbox? Or is it a string? You must give us more details about your problems.

Comment: Please show the full method so we can see what 'A' is.

Comment: A and B is text box i changed Atextbox.text its worked at first but i cant use decimals so i tried to change but now its giving same error again. And literally its full code there is a combo box that i can choose formula then 2 text box a calculate button and a label for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make k `float`

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(A);
int y = Convert.ToInt32(B);
float k = (x * 100) / y;  //CHANGE
string z = k.ToString();
finalstring.Text= z;
```

#### EDITED

```
int x = Int16.Parse("100"); //CHANGE 1
int y = Int16.Parse("10"); //CHANGE 2
int k = (x * 100) / y; //CHANGE 3
string z = k.ToString();
Console.WriteLine("ANSWER : " + z);
```

Comment: still same error

Answer (score 0):

```
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(AtextBox1.Text);// changed to A to atextbox.text
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(BtextBox.Text);
        float k = (x * 100) / y;  //CHANGE
        string z = k.ToString();
        finalstring.Text = z;
```

at first it didnt work but i guess its worked this time bc changing int k to float k

#### Edited

i changed code entirely and it worked

double x = Convert.ToDouble(AtextBox1.Text);

double y = Convert.ToDouble(BtextBox.Text);

finalstring.Text = ((x / 100) * y).ToString();